# Updating Linux Mint Without Internet Access

Tags: linux-mint, usb

I can't afford to have an internet connection at home. Is there any way of figuring out what update I need for my system so that I can download the same onto my USB stick from the office internet connection, take it home and then update my system with the USB stick.

EDIT: I'm using windows 7 in the office which is connected to the internet and I need to download all the updates that are needed for the proper functioning of my Linux mint system at home.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [apt-offline](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-offline).

> apt-offline can fully update and upgrade an APT based distribution without connecting to the network, all of it transparent to APT.
>
> apt-offline can be used to generate a signature on a machine (with no network). This signature contains all download information required for the APT database system. This signature file can be used on another machine connected to the internet (which need not be a Debian box and can even be running windows) to download the updates. The downloaded data will contain all updates in a format understood by APT and this data can be used by apt-offline to update the non-networked machine.

There is also a GUI version: [apt-offline-gui](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/apt-offline-gui)

[image: screenshot]

More information in the howto [Offline Package Management for APT](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT) and [an answer on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/166257/36085)

Comment: How do i download apt-offline GUI for windows 7? I'm sorry i'm unable to follow anything on it.

Comment: @alok I added some more information. `apt-offline` is just a python script and one should be able to run the same version on different operating systems. I'm not sure if the GUI version works on windows.

Comment: In any case, `apt-offline --upgrade set somefile` outputs a list of files to download. The first column contains the files in question which can be downloaded, e.g. with `wget`.