# Installing Packages Offline On Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, usb, packaging

Is it possible to create a linux software package on windows ,store it on a USB stick and then install it on a linux system which is not connected to the internet ?

For example I would like to install the latest version of GCC on my linux mint system which is not connected to the internet after going through the prerequisites (http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html)

I understand that a much better option as i'm using Linux mint 15 (Olivia) which is ubuntu/debian based is to download and install dpkg dev package and GNU make,but i'm afraid that the dependency error might pop up again.
I tried doing that yesterday after unzipping the file but i get dependency related errors.

Instead of separately installing the dependencies one after the other without knowing the dependencies is it possible to create a package called GCC with all dependencies "linked",store it on a USB stick,take it home,plug it in and then build it?

As i mentioned earlier i'm using Windows 7 in the office.
(see [Updating Linux Mint Without Internet Access](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90848/updating-linux-mint-without-internet-access))

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one? `apt-offline` does exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this wrong. Don't manually install the packages. It's sloppy, you won't remember what you've done and you don't tell the package manager.

Instead, just use `dpkg --install`.

If you're manually installing a tarball, don't. The only reason you should be doing that is if you're using Linux From Scratch. Otherwise use your package manager - it's there for a reason.

Comment: I'm using linux from scratch.the usual procedure for installing software from source is to unpack first and then run configure-->make-->make install right? that's exactly what i want to accomplish. Can i do the same with dpkg --install? I'm sorry if the question looks stupid. I'm in a helpless situation without an internet connection.

Comment: If you're using Mint you should be using `dpkg`. On Linux from Scratch you should be untarring and compiling. I got confused because you said you were using Linux Mint.